# Python Manipulating a list of tuples using a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, tuples

I am trying to write a python function which uses a while loop to iterate through an input list of tuples containing dates and number of steps walked on each date. The two inputs of my function are the list and a number of required steps. The function needs to go through the list and count up how many days it took to reach the required number of steps. Below is my code so far which works for the initial part however I need to also add to it so that if the required number of steps is not reached in the input list of tuples, the function returns 'None'. Another thing is that I can only have one return statement because the question states so, which is partially why I am stuck on it.

```
def days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, n):
  """DOCSTRING"""
  total_steps = 0
  counter = 0
  while total_steps < n:
      total_steps = total_steps + step_records[counter][1]
      counter = counter + 1
  return(counter)
```

An example of what I am testing my function with, this particular example should return `None` as the steps in the list do not ever reach or exceed 50.

`step_records = [('2010-01-01',3),
                ('2010-01-02',2),
                ('2010-01-03',1)]
days = days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, 50)
print(days)`

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what `step_records` looks like (why is it a list of tuples if you're only using one part?), and what your expected output is vs what you're getting so far?

Comment: Edited my question with a sample of what I am calling the function with. I will be using the date part of `step_records` after modifying the function to also return the date at which `n` was reached, however I thought it would be best to leave this part out of the question because I thought I should focus on figuring out the initial part, first.

Comment: What number of days/date would you return if `n` was 0?

Comment: Not going to lie I hadn't thought of that. I guess an output of  0 or `None` would be fine for that case as well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that the easiest solution is a `for` loop here, as fundamentally what you want is iteration. You can also use `enumerate` to keep track of the day:

```
sample_steps = [("2010-01-1", 1),
                ("2010-01-2", 3),
                ("2010-01-3", 5),
                ("2010-01-4", 7),
                ("2010-01-5", 9),
                ("2010-01-6", 11)]

def days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, n):
    total_steps = 0
    for counter, (date, steps) in enumerate(step_records, 1):
        total_steps += steps
        if total_steps >= n:
            return counter, date
```

I've chosen the odd numbers as the sequence of steps as their cumulative sums are the squares (makes it easier to check by eye):

```
for boundary in range(1, 7):
    for steps in range(boundary ** 2 - 1, boundary ** 2 + 2):
        result = days_to_reach_n_steps(sample_steps, steps)
        if result:
            days, date = result
            print("{} steps in {} days (arrived at {})".format(steps, days, date))
        else:
            print("{} was unreached".format(steps))
```

This will return this:

```
0 steps in 1 days (arrived at 2010-01-1)
1 steps in 1 days (arrived at 2010-01-1)
2 steps in 2 days (arrived at 2010-01-2)
3 steps in 2 days (arrived at 2010-01-2)
4 steps in 2 days (arrived at 2010-01-2)
5 steps in 3 days (arrived at 2010-01-3)
8 steps in 3 days (arrived at 2010-01-3)
9 steps in 3 days (arrived at 2010-01-3)
10 steps in 4 days (arrived at 2010-01-4)
15 steps in 4 days (arrived at 2010-01-4)
16 steps in 4 days (arrived at 2010-01-4)
17 steps in 5 days (arrived at 2010-01-5)
24 steps in 5 days (arrived at 2010-01-5)
25 steps in 5 days (arrived at 2010-01-5)
26 steps in 6 days (arrived at 2010-01-6)
35 steps in 6 days (arrived at 2010-01-6)
36 steps in 6 days (arrived at 2010-01-6)
37 was unreached
```

Note that `days_to_reach_n_steps` only has one `return` statement, but still manages to `return` `None` for `37`. This is because implicitly a function not returning anything returns `None`. However this doesn't quite match your specification for 0. I'd recommend doing this if you want 0 to be exceptional:

```
for counter, (date, steps) in enumerate([("start", 0)] + step_records):
```

The first line of the answer will change to

```
0 steps in 0 days (arrived at start)
```

This maintains the rest of the algorithm, so you don't need to program edge cases.

If it has to be a while loop, you can slightly facetiously rewrite the for loop into this:

```
def days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, n):
    total_steps = 0
    counter = 0
    step_records = [("start", 0)] + step_records
    while counter < len(step_records):
        date, steps = step_records[counter]
        total_steps += steps
        if total_steps >= n:
            return counter, date
        counter += 1
```

This works exactly the same as the second iteration of the for loop approach (`$ diff <(python while.py) <(python code.py)` exits cleanly).

To adapt it to be like the first iteration of the for loop, remove the reassignment to `step_records` and return `counter + 1`.

Beware that this isn't really a good application of a while loop - maybe the intention is to gain practice with while loops but I don't really approve of forcing ugly code - Python already has simple idioms for iterating over lists and keeping indices. See [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Yeah I have solved this problem with a for loop before but the question says it does not allow for loops and that while loops must be used instead. Any other possible solutions using a while loop?

Comment: You are a legend. Upvoted and marked as answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Exit at `IndexError` and set `c` to `None` when not reached:

```
def daystoreach(steprecords, n):
total = 0
x = 0
while total < n:
    try:
        total += sr[x][1]
        x += 1
    except IndexError:
        break
if total < n:
    x = None
return x
```

Comment: I would really recommend using more expressive variable names than that - had I not been working with the expansions of your abbreviations I'd have no idea what a `dtrns` was.

Comment: Did it(yes,very late)